# How to update hierarchical ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am stuck with this problem.

I have a model AssessmentModel defined like this:

```
public class AssessmentModel
{
    public Respondent Respondent { get; set; }
    public List<CompetencyModel> Competencies { get; set; }
}

public class CompetencyModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ResultModel> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ResultModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

All I need is to set value to the Score property of ResultModel.
Score is the only editable property here.

And I have just 1 View only, this view has a @model List, it displays a list of CompetencyModel items with Edit button for each one.
When I click the Edit button, the Id of CompetencyModel is passed to the same View, and the View draws an Edit form for ResultModel items that belong to the selected CompetencyModel.

However the form for ResultModel items exists on the same View, and the model of the View is still @model List.

How can I get to the Score property by using bindable Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Score) helper for each ResultModel item?

The View is defined like this:

```
@model List<CompetencyModel>
@foreach(var comp in Model)
{
    <p>@comp.Name</p>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Assessment", new { comp.Id })">Edit</a>
}
```

In the controller I set ViewBag.CurrentId = comp.Id, and at the bottom of the View:

```
if(ViewBag.CurrentId != null) //draw a form for ResultModel items
{
 // What should I do now? 
 // how cant I use Html.EditorFor(m=>...) if the Model is still List<CompetencyModel>
}
```

I need to get to a single ResultModel entity to set a value to a Score property.

Thank you.

Comment: I've read thru your post, and while i understand each part, i find im lost

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this done using Linq. Consider having the following code segment in the your last if statement

```
var result = Model.Results.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == ViewBag.CurrentId);
```

I dont have a IDE with me, so watchout for syntext errors